# Are there utilities to help automate backing up Azure SQL databases to Azure Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-scheduler

I know SQL-Azure has automated backups that are retained for 30 days, but for archival purposes I also need to take and retain other backups: daily (last 60 days), weekly (first day of each week for the last 8 weeks), monthly (first day of each month for the last 12 months).  At the end of a period, the last backup gets deleted (except for monthly).  Any daily backups older than 60 days gets deleted, etc.  The monthly backups would get moved to **cold** storage where they are saved for years.

I should note that my databases are only in the 2-4 GB range, so the cost savings of using Azure's cold storage may be so minimal that it's not even worth bothering moving the monthly backups to cold storage.

I was thinking blob storage is probably the way to go.  Are there utilities, scripts, etc that do this? I don't want to reinvent the wheel.  I see Azure has a scheduling service which would be nice to use because the free version would more  than suffice, but I don't want to overcomplicate things.  If I need to run a cheap VM just for backups I will.

Comment: I would use Azure Automation and Powershell to shift your backups around. Running a cheap VM is going to overcomplicate things. (Then you have to have a network, access, operating system, patches, security etc to worry about)

Comment: I think cherrysafe (formerly redgate's backup) or powershell would be the two options closest to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There is Cherry Safe 
https://www.cherrysafe.com/Home/Features#sqlAzureBackup

This tool is flexible and not very expensive.

This article may also help you
http://fabriccontroller.net/backup-and-restore-your-sql-azure-database-using-powershell/

Comment: Anyone used Cherry Safe? Credibility is important for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

We have a private preview of long term backup retention feature in Azure SQL. If you are interested to join please email to sashan at microsoft.com for details.